# Image Comparing and return Percentage

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, comparison

```
int DiferentPixels = 0;
Bitmap first = new Bitmap("First.jpg");
Bitmap second = new Bitmap("Second.jpg");
Bitmap container = new Bitmap(first.Width, first.Height);
for (int i = 0; i < first.Width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < first.Height; j++)
    {
    int r1 = second.GetPixel(i, j).R;
    int g1 = second.GetPixel(i, j).G;
    int b1 = second.GetPixel(i, j).B;

    int r2 = first.GetPixel(i, j).R;
    int g2 = first.GetPixel(i, j).G;
    int b2 = first.GetPixel(i, j).B;

    if (r1 != r2 && g1 != g2 && b1 != b2)
    {
    DiferentPixels++;
    container.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Red);
    }
    else
    container.SetPixel(i, j, first.GetPixel(i, j));
    }
}
int TotalPixels = first.Width * first.Height;
float dierence = (float)((float)DiferentPixels / (float)TotalPixels);
float percentage = dierence * 100;
```

With this portion of Code im comparing 2 Images foreach Pixels and yes it work's it return's Percentage of difference ,so it compares each Pixel of First Image with pixel in same index of Second Image .But what is wrong here ,i have a huge precision maybe it should not work like that ,the comparison ,and maybe there are some better algorithms which are faster and more flexible .
So anyone has an idea how can i transform  the comparison ,should i continue with that or should i compare Colors of Each Pixels or ....

PS : If anyone has a solution how to make Parallel this code ,i would also accept it ! Like expanding this to 4 Threads would they do it faster right in a Quad Core?

Comment: How large is the image?  It might not be worth parallelizing the code unless they're pretty big or you have a lot of them.

Comment: @Matt Image size is not the concern ,but the case is it will compare lot of images continuously ,like 100 !That's bothers me.

Comment: that seems like a good candidate for parallelizing the code then

Comment: @Matt any suggestion where to start because i really really need to tune this up

Comment: Who voted down ,i would really really like to know why? Because better ideas is what im waiting for = ) have the courage and tell me why Voted Down !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One obvious change would be call `GetPixel` only once per `Bitmap`, and then work with the returned `Color` structs directly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < first.Width; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < first.Height; ++j)
    {
        Color secondColor = second.GetPixel(i, j);
        Color firstColor = first.GetPixel(i, j);

        if (firstColor != secondColor)
        {
            DiferentPixels++;
            container.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            container.SetPixel(i, j, firstColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this will save Memory and CPU or only one of em ?

Comment: @Cody Mainly CPU. It does keep it from making 6 ints every loop but they are short lived and on the stack so the memory portion does not really matter.

Answer (score 6):

For speed, resize the images to something very small (16x12, for example) and do the pixel comparison. If it is a near match, then try it at higher resolution.

Comment: nice idea i`ll try it out ,but sory i cannot accept it because i expecting more answers ,i think my problem needs more suggestion's like that thanks again