# Free/open library to find similar images

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I'm looking for stable and mature free/opensource library allows to compare two images.

I found this one but I want to know if you use a better one!

- [Similar images finder - .NET Image processing in C# and RGB](http://similarimagesfinder.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I just tried the one you linked to...on an image set of about 1000 images, it took about 3 minutes on my PC and aside from the first 2 or 3 results, the rest were pretty horrible (images were nothing alike).

Answer (score 9):

I did it simply.Just download EyeOpen Library [here](http://similarimagesfinder.codeplex.com/).
then use it in your c# class and write this:

```
 use eyeopen.imaging.processing
```

write

```
ComparableImage cc;

ComparableImage pc;

int sim;

void compare(object sender, EventArgs e){
    pc = new ComparableImage(new FileInfo(files));
    cc = new ComparableImage(new FileInfo(file));

    pc.CalculateSimilarity(cc);
    sim = pc.CalculateSimilarity(cc);

    int sim2 = sim*100

    Messagebox.show(sim2 + "% similar");

}
```

Comment: It's a shame that the public api exposes only a constructor with `FileInfo` parameter. Nevertheless source is available.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks! the int should be a double though.

Answer (score 0):

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ this one or use this Question if you want to know how can you find it out by you're self [Image Comparing and return Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598048/image-comparing-and-return-percentage)